# Using SMO from multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading, smo

I am using the SQL Server Managment Objects in my application. Most operations on the SMO objects in the application are directly triggered from the UI. E.g. a user manipulating an object which results in reading or writing properties from an SMO object (Table, View, ...).

Now I want to introduce a background operation which will regulary scan through some objects (read only).

My question is if this can cause problems with SMO. From the documentation I know that the instance members of the objects are not thread safe. So my plan is to put a lock on each single SMO object whenever I access it from the UI or the background thread. But what happens if I access two different objects (e.g. a View and a Table) at the same time. Even if I do only a read of a property, the object might not have been initalized completely and needs to be loaded from the databse. So in the worst case SMO would need to initalize both objects at the same time. Since I don't know how SMO handles this internally, I was wondering if anyone knows if this is allowed by SMO or if it will cause problems.

Any other suggestions on how to solve this? I would like to avoid having a global lock for the whole SMO library...

Thanks!

Comment: Need to better define "some objects" of "will regularly scan some objects".   What types of operations are you doing on the SMO objects?

Comment: I'm reading the name and schema from all standard database objects (database, table, view, stored procedures) to display a database tree to the user like in the SQL Server Managment studio. Then I'm reading and writing the MS_Description attribute for these objects, which is inside ExtendedProperties. The background thread READS the same properties regulary.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by global lock object nor not initialized completely.  You don't have access to an object until it is initialized completely.   If you initialize two objects at the same time then you have two objects.  What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I use SMO and what i learn is that if you want to make some usual operations (scripting...) it is usefull.But if you want to really manage database objects, it will be better to use system stored procedure (so SMO will not be another layer to understand).Using stored procedure allow you to lock data or not and will be a possible solution

Comment: Well, I don't have too many requirements. I don't really need a lot of database "managment". See my comment above. Just want to dsiplay a database tree to the user and read/write some properties.

Comment: hi, if you want to initialize properties of your database object you can use SetDefaultInitFields of your server object.

Comment: I know about SetDefaultInitFields. Sorry, but how is this related to the question? The question is what happens if you initalize 2 objects at the same time.